# Supertest Error: expected '[]' response body, got '[""]'

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, redis, supertest

I'm not sure why I keep getting this error. Whenever I run npm test I get this full error:

```
1) Listing subscriptions on /subscriptions
   Returns initial subscriptions:
 Error: expected '[]' response body, got '[""]'
  at error (node_modules\supertest\lib\test.js:299:13)
  at Test._assertBody (node_modules\supertest\lib\test.js:216:14)
  at Test._assertFunction (node_modules\supertest\lib\test.js:281:11)
  at Test.assert (node_modules\supertest\lib\test.js:171:18)
  at Server.assert (node_modules\supertest\lib\test.js:131:12)
  at emitCloseNT (net.js:1543:8)
  at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:71:11)
  at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:98:9)
```

In my app.js file:

```js
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var urlencode = bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false });

app.use(express.static('public'));

var redis = require('redis');
if (process.env.REDISTOGO_URL) {
    var rtg = require('url').parse(process.env.REDISTOGO_URL);
    var client = redis.createClient(rtg.port, rtg.hostname);
    client.auth(rtg.auth.split(":")[1]);
} else {
    var client = redis.createClient();
    client.select((process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development').length);
}

app.get('/subscriptions', function (req, res) {
    client.hkeys('subscriptions', function (err, names) {
        if (err) throw err;
        res.json(names);
    });
});


app.post('/subscriptions', urlencode, function (req, res) {
var newSubscription = req.body;
if(!newSubscription.name || !newSubscription.date) {
    res.sendStatus(400);
    return false;
}
client.hset('subscriptions', newSubscription.name,  newSubscription.date, 
function (err) {
    if (err) throw err;
    res.status(201).json(newSubscription.name);
});
});
```

test.js file:

```js
var request = require('supertest');
var app = require('./app');

var redis = require('redis');
var client = redis.createClient();
client.select('test'.length);
client.flushdb();

describe('Requests to the root path', function () {

    it('Returns a 200 status code', function (done) {

        request(app)
            .get('/')
            .expect(200, done);
    });
    it('Returns a HTML format', function(done) {
        
        request(app)
            .get('/')
            .expect('Content-Type', /html/, done);
    });
    it('Returns an index file with Subscriptions', function(done) {

        request(app)
            .get('/')
            .expect(/subscriptions/i, done);
    });
});

describe('Listing subscriptions on /subscriptions', function () {

    it('Returns 200 status code', function (done) {

        request(app)
            .get('/subscriptions')
            .expect(200, done);

    });
    it('Returns JSON format', function (done) {

        request(app)
            .get('/subscriptions')
            .expect('Content-Type', /json/, done);
    });

    it('Returns initial subscriptions', function (done) {

        request(app)
            .get('/subscriptions')
            .expect(JSON.stringify([]), done);
    });
});
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up using

```js
client.flushall();
```

in place of

```js
client.flushdb();
```

It flushed out all existing data (though I'm not sure how it got in there to begin with). Afterwards I changed it back and it's working fine.